# In Bootstrap should separate input fields be put inside own col or share col to keep them together, right justified

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap should separate input fields be put inside their own `col` or share `col` to keep them together, right justified.

I have a combo and input that I want to be shown on the same row on the right-hand side of the screen. If I put it together in a `col-4`

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-4 ms-auto m-2">
    <select id="sort_list" style="display: inline" class="form-select m-2">
      <option value="sortname_asc">
        Sort by Sortname ascending
      </option>
      <option value="sortname_desc">
        Sort by Sortname descending
      </option>
      <option value="name_asc">
        Sort by Name ascending
      </option>
      <option value="name_desc">
        Sort by Name descending
      </option>
    </select>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">
                                Filter
                            </span>
      <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

they are shown on top of each other

If I put in their own col-2s then only the second one is right-justified, the other one is in the center

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-2 ms-auto m-2">
    <select id="sort_list" style="display: inline" class="form-select m-2">
      <option value="sortname_asc">
        Sort by Sortname ascending
      </option>
      <option value="sortname_desc">
        Sort by Sortname descending
      </option>
      <option value="name_asc">
        Sort by Name ascending
      </option>
      <option value="name_desc">
        Sort by Name descending
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 ms-auto m-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">
                                Filter
                            </span>
      <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried adding `style="display: inline"` to the input field but made no difference. What is the correct way of doing this?

It seems that **select** elements will use all the available space, so in the first case, if I used a larger number of columns (e.g col-8) then all that space will always be used by the first select, never shared with the text input field

**Update**

Answer from Cervus seems to work, except I need to keep ms-auto or first column will just expand to take up whole, why is that, this is my code

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
        <div class="row justify-content-end">
            <span class="col col-auto m-2">
                <span class="input-group">
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="sort_list">
                        Sort By
                    </label>
                    <select id="sort_list" name="sort_list" class="form-select" onchange="sort(this);">
                        <option value="sortname_asc">
                            Sort Name Up
                        </option>
                        <option value="sortname_desc">
                            Sort Name Down
                        </option>
                        <option value="name_asc">
                            Name Up
                        </option>
                        <option value="name_desc">
                            Name Down
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="col-2 col-auto m-2">
                <span class="input-group">
                    <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">
                        Filter
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

If I remove col-auto I get first column too wide

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
        <div class="row justify-content-end">
            <span class="col m-2">
                <span class="input-group">
                    <label class="input-group-text" for="sort_list">
                        Sort By
                    </label>
                    <select id="sort_list" name="sort_list" class="form-select" onchange="sort(this);">
                        <option value="sortname_asc">
                            Sort Name Up
                        </option>
                        <option value="sortname_desc">
                            Sort Name Down
                        </option>
                        <option value="name_asc">
                            Name Up
                        </option>
                        <option value="name_desc">
                            Name Down
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="col-2 m-2">
                <span class="input-group">
                    <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">
                        Filter
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The solution

It's very easy, you were close. Do the following:

1. Remove the class `ms-auto` from both `col-2` elements.
2. Add classes `d-flex align-items-center` to the second `col-2` element to center the content vertically.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-2 m-2">
    <select id="sort_list" style="display: inline" class="form-select m-2">
      <option value="sortname_asc">
        Sort by Sortname ascending
      </option>
      <option value="sortname_desc">
        Sort by Sortname descending
      </option>
      <option value="name_asc">
        Sort by Name ascending
      </option>
      <option value="name_desc">
        Sort by Name descending
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 d-flex align-items-center m-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">Filter</span>
      <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Set `max-width: 280px !important;` to the first column.

See the snippet below.

```css
#first_column {
    max-width: 280px !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <span class="col m-2" id="first_column">
    <span class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="sort_list">
            Sort By
        </label>
        <select id="sort_list" name="sort_list" class="form-select" onchange="sort(this);">
            <option value="sortname_asc">
                Sort Name Up
            </option>
            <option value="sortname_desc">
                Sort Name Down
            </option>
            <option value="name_asc">
                Name Up
            </option>
            <option value="name_desc">
                Name Down
            </option>
        </select>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="col-2 m-2" id="second_column">
    <span class="input-group">
      <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">
          Filter
      </span>
      <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: So if you put justify-content-end on the row then all cols within the row will be right justisfied, is that right ?

Comment: I used modified version of your code for a solution and added as update to question, however I found I need to keep ms-auto and I dont need d-flex align-items-center as they already seem to be alighned vertically with each other, could yo explain please.

Comment: Yes, correct. If you set `justify-content-end` on the row then all columns within the row will be right aligned. I read the update. What do you mean by saying *first column will just expand to take up whole*? Why is necessary to keep the class `ms-auto`?

Comment: Added another code snippet to question showing first col now taking up whole row if remove col-auto

Comment: I updated my answer. Set `max-width: 280px !important;` to the first column.

Comment: Why 280px, seems rather arbitary, why not use col-auto?

Comment: I agree, but you removed `col-auto`. Setting `width` is another way to prevent the column to take all the remaining space.

Comment: Sorry I thought you told me to remove col-auto but you actually said ms-auto, however in your first code snippet there is no col-auto so I don't understand why in your solution it doesn't take up the whole row ?

Answer (score 0):

This puts both input fields on the same row and it should justify it to the right. Does this do what you are expecting?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div class="input-group m-2 col-4">
      <select id="sort_list" class="form-select form-control">
        <option value="sortname_asc">
          Sort by Sortname ascending
        </option>
        <option value="sortname_desc">
          Sort by Sortname descending
        </option>
        <option value="name_asc">
          Sort by Name ascending
        </option>
        <option value="name_desc">
          Sort by Name descending
        </option>
      </select>
      <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">
        Filter
      </span>
      <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So the difference is you put both inputs into a single input-group, I thought an input-group was a way to put an integrated label and input, am i wrong or is this a bit of a hack ?

Comment: Input groups are anything you want to make into one contiguous input "field" for lack of a better term. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/input-group/#basic-example In that, if you look at the "username", "@", "server" you can see that its for putting arbitrary inputs/labels together into one "input group".

Comment: okay, in this case the two fields are not part of the same thing really, so this is not right solution, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, I didn't really understand what you were asking.